# Windows 8 VirtualBox Vt-x not available

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox

I just upgraded my host machine from windows 7 to windows 8. I was running an OSX VM under VirtualBox for iOS dev. Since the upgrade I can no longer run my OSX VM. I get the error VT-x not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

I checked the bios setting and hardware virtualization is still on. Which would only make sense since the only thing that changed was the OS.

Comment: Ask on http://superuser.com/

Comment: I had the same problem when I migrated to Windows 8 for the VMs I had setup for testing my app across different operating systems. Reducing memory seemed to fix the problem, though I had to keep it at or below 3GB. Perhaps Windows 8 artificially imposes a limit?

Comment: Disable Hyper-V feature. See here:
See here: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=52191

Comment: This question is closed, but I want to say that for anyone with VT-x enabled in BIOS, but not working in VirtualBox: disable VT-d in your BIOS.

Comment: @JeffWinn, adjusting the memory fixed my issue, thank you.

Comment: First check your bios. then disable Hyper-V. Here is detailed instruction how to do that: http://druss.co/2015/06/fix-vt-x-is-not-available-verr_vmx_no_vmx-in-virtualbox/